# Visual Studio 2022 building solution with CMAKE all options are presented with "<different options>" string

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, cmake

I downloaded visual studio 2022 and whenever I build solution with CMAKE 3.2 and then loading it in to VC++ I'm getting the values presented as `"<different options>"` string.

However I know it's defined as "some" value.

For example:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the top left corner it says `Configuration`, click `All Configurations`. Pick a `Configuration` like `Debug` or `Release`

The compiler options will differ between the builds for performance/debug purposes.

Once you select a configuration it will show you the actual compiler option(s).